# bool variable is not able to capture if any user is logged in, although print(user) is printing a signed in user (Flutter web app)

Tags: flutter, authentication, initialization

Trying to get the status if user is signed in the main function of flutter web app by overriding initstate method. Although, I'm successfully logged in through a sign in screen in the previous run of my app, I always get the value false for isSignedIn, but not true.
Below is part of code. Let me know if more details are required.

//Importing necessary packages and files here including material, go_router, firebase_core, firebase_auth etc.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User? customer;
bool? isSignedIn;

@override
  void initState() {
    Future<User?> _signedInCustomer() async {
      await _auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
        print('user=\n$user');
        if (user != null) {
          customer = user;
        } else {
          customer = null;
        }
      });
      return customer;
    }

    bool _isSignedIn(user) {
      if (user != null) {
        return true;
      } else
        return false;
    }

    Future<void> _setIsSignedIn() async {
      isSignedIn = await _signedInCustomer().then((user) => _isSignedIn(user));
      print('isSignedIn = $isSignedIn');
    }

    _setIsSignedIn();
    super.initState();
  }
```

//I'm using the bool isSignedIn variable as below

```
late final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: "/",
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: "home",
        path: "/",
        builder: (context, state) => MyHomePage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
          name: "signin",
          path: "/signin",
          pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
              CustomAnimatedNavigation(key: state.pageKey, child: AuthPage())),
      GoRoute(
        name: "orders",
        path: "/orders",
        pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
            CustomAnimatedNavigation(key: state.pageKey, child: MyOrders()),
        redirect: (context, state) async {
          if (isSignedIn!) {
            return "/orders";
          } else if (state.location != '/signin') {
            return "/signin";
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
//Code for @override Widget build() here
}
```

//Order button on first home page trigger the route to signin or orders page like this  `onPressed: () => context.push('/orders')`

Expecting to get value of bool variable isSignedIn to be true but always getting false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `authStateChanges` wrong. Try using it like this:

First define a stream subscription where you define `_auth` (inside your class):

```dart
late StreamSubscription authStreamSubscription;
```

Then inside `initState`:

```dart
authStreamSubscription = _auth.authStateChanges.listen((User?) { 
 setState(() => isSignedIn = user != null);
});
```

Then again in your class define the `dispose` method:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
 authStreamSubscription.cancel();
 super.dipose();
}
```

Note: you will probably need to import `dart:async`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It worked after some syntax correction. Things I understood are 1) setState will help to change build when somehow user auth status changes 2) stream subscription will keep listening to the status and not only run on app start?? Question? In my initial code, future was returning customer as null because it was returning before future completion? help me understand plz.

Comment: I’m sorry for the syntax error, I wrote the answer from my phone. Yes, it listens and will be called whenever the auth state changes, eg. when the user signs out and then signs in again. Your initial code it wasn’t working because you were using authStateChanges.listen in the wrong  way, authStateChanges.listen doesn’t even return a Future, it returns a StreamSubscription<User?>. It was returning null because you probably weren’t signed.